# how use break statement on powershell "switch -regex -file"?

Tags: regex, powershell

i'm using the next function to parse one ini file.

I have one problem that i don't know how to solve:

If one match is found, break loop and read next line.

I know that i can put break to do this. But, break exit of all switch code. ¿?

I suppose it's a special scenario when using switch with regex to parse a file.

**¿How can i do to not parse same line in two code blocks?**

See in the output:

```
`Comment ; Parameters that are strings are specified parameter=string, like this:`
`Key ; Parameters that are strings are specified parameter=string, like this:`

and

`Comment ; Parameters that are numbers are specified parameter=number, like this:` 
`Key ; Parameters that are numbers are specified parameter=number, like this:`
```

**Thanks**

```
    function Get-IniContent ($filePath)  
    {  
        $ini = @{}   
        switch -regex -file $FilePath   
        {   
            "^\[(.+)\]$" # Section   
            {   
                $section = $matches[1]   
                $ini[$section] = @{}   
                $CommentCount = 0   
                Write-Host "Section $section"  
            }   
            "^(;.*)$" # Comment   
            {   
                if (!($section))   
                {   
                    $section = "No-Section"   
                    $ini[$section] = @{}   
                }   
                $value = $matches[1]   
                $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1   
                $name = "Comment" + $CommentCount   
                $ini[$section][$name] = $value   
                Write-Host "Comment $value"  
            }    
            "(.+?)\s*=\s*(.*)" # Key   
            {   
                if (!($section))   
                {   
                    $section = "No-Section"   
                    $ini[$section] = @{}   
                }   
                $name,$value = $matches[1..2]   
                $ini[$section][$name] = $value   
                Write-Host "Key $name=$value"  
            }   
            default  
            {              
                # Next line causes NullArray error  
                #$line=$matches[1]  
                Write-Host "Strange line $line"  
            }  
        }   

        return $ini  
    }  

    $iniFile=Get-IniContent (Join-Path (Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) "test.config")
```

This it's a sample ini file:

```
Independent Bad Line
timer=19
[Common]
; 4 - default value hard-coded in ntfs-hardlink-backup.ps1 script

; Blank lines also do no harm

; Parameters that are strings are specified parameter=string, like this:
backupDestination=X:\Backup
; Parameters that are numbers are specified parameter=number, like this:
backupsToKeep=20

[server-01.mycompany.example.org]
; Parameters that are specific to a particular server/computer go in a section for that computer.
; The section name is the fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) of the computer.
backupSources=D:\Shares\Admin,E:\Shares\Finance,E:\Shares\ICT,D:\Shares\Users
:Bad Line
=10 ; Also Bad Line
```

And this it's script output:

```
E:\Config\NtfsBackup>powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file "E:\Config\NtfsBackup\nt1.ps1" 
Strange line 
Key timer=19
Section Common
Comment ; 4 - default value hard-coded in ntfs-hardlink-backup.ps1 script
Strange line 
Comment ; Blank lines also do no harm
Strange line 
Comment ; Parameters that are strings are specified parameter=string, like this:
Key ; Parameters that are strings are specified parameter=string, like this:
Key backupDestination=X:\Backup
Comment ; Parameters that are numbers are specified parameter=number, like this:
Key ; Parameters that are numbers are specified parameter=number, like this:
Key backupsToKeep=20
Strange line 
Section server-01.mycompany.example.org
Comment ; Parameters that are specific to a particular server/computer go in a section for that computer.
Comment ; The section name is the fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) of the computer.
Key backupSources=D:\Shares\Admin,E:\Shares\Finance,E:\Shares\ICT,D:\Shares\Users
Strange line 
Strange line
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple. You do not want to use `Break` but instead use `Continue` which will stop the loop for the current item and start the loop for the next item. Placing `Continue` at the end of all of your script blocks (probably on a new line just after the `Write-Host` line) for the switch will do what you need.

```
function Get-IniContent ($filePath)  
{  
    $ini = @{}   
    switch -regex -file $FilePath   
    {   
        "^\[(.+)\]$" # Section   
        {   
            $section = $matches[1]   
            $ini[$section] = @{}   
            $CommentCount = 0   
            Write-Host "Section $section"
            Continue
        }   
        "^(;.*)$" # Comment   
        {   
            if (!($section))   
            {   
                $section = "No-Section"   
                $ini[$section] = @{}   
            }   
            $value = $matches[1]   
            $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1   
            $name = "Comment" + $CommentCount   
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value   
            Write-Host "Comment $value"  
            Continue
        }    
        "(.+?)\s*=\s*(.*)" # Key   
        {   
            if (!($section))   
            {   
                $section = "No-Section"   
                $ini[$section] = @{}   
            }   
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]   
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value   
            Write-Host "Key $name=$value"  
            Continue
        }   
        default  
        {              
            # Next line causes NullArray error  
            #$line=$matches[1]  
            Write-Host "Strange line $line"  
        }  
    }   

    return $ini  
}  

$iniFile=Get-IniContent (Join-Path (Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) "test.config")
```

Comment: Thanks @TheMadTechnician. Works like a charm :)

All the samples I've found online about using regex and file in a switch block come with __break__ and none appeared __continue__